# Versions for integration of apache flink, elasticsearch and kafka

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have problems with different versions of Flink, Kafka and Elastic Search. I'm using Flink 1.8.1 version but I don't know what version to use for Kafka. On the other hand, I want to use the version 6 for Elastic Search. Which versions do you think are suitable for Flink, Kafka and Elastic Search?
The following link is a version of Kafka, but in the comments section, it is introduced as a beta
[enter link description here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/connectors/kafka.html)

Answer (score 2):

As listed in the table, Kafka 0.11 (and higher) will work fine. The beta is a version of the Flink Connector, not Kafka itself

Plus, Kafka Connect for Elasticsearch, should you choose to use it, works for elasticsearch 6

Answer (score 1):

As @cricket_007 said, it's safe to use the Kafka connector, even though it is labeled beta (which should be removed as this connector has now been battle-tested since over a year in production).

The setup Kafka -> Flink -> ES6 is quite common, so you can and should use recent version on all involved components.